# Unable to save simple data into Parse database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm following the quickstart guide to using Parse for Android and adding simple data into the database.

I added the following code to the OnCreate of my mainactivity:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("WHYCANNOT");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
    Log.i("debug", testObject.toString());
```

I checked my data browser and I don't see anything. Am i doing anything wrong? How can I tell if it is the problem with my connection?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I forgot to add the permission to use Internet in my manifest, but there isn't any error message to reflect this.